# How to use a json file with a single controller app in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I don't know how to make a service for a json file and call this service in my controller.
I have one controller in my app,and so must remain.

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: I don't have an error, I don't view the json file content on my screen.

Comment: Where do you call  `userAService` and `getUserData` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this example via `run code snippet` blue button.

Basically, You need to declare that service, the require it via `Angular.DI`, lastly call the service method and wait for its result.
Hope it helps

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .constant('API' , 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')
  .service('TestService', function(API, $http) {
      
    this.getData = function() {
      return $http
        .get(API + '/photos')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        })
      };
  })
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, TestService) {
  
  //But a Resolve is preferred
  TestService
    .getData()
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.album = data;
    })
  ;
})
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="photo in album">
      <h3 ng-bind="photo.title"></h3>
      <img ng-src="{{photo.thumbnailUrl}}" />
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your service from your controller.

your service:

```
angular.module('YOURAPP')
.service("userAService",  function ($http) {
                this.promise= function () {
                    return $http.get('resources/json/data.json')
                }
    });
```

And then in your controller function:

```
mycontroller = function(userAService){
     userAService.promise().then(
         function(response){
             //do what you want in your promise
             // try console.log(response.data) to see if you get your data.
         }
     )
}
```